# Extract and parse JSON Data with Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, openstack, openstack-api

I want to ask how to get the list IP Address in my getproject():

```
addresses={
  'int-ext': [
    {
      'version': 4,
      'addr': '192.168.1.201',
      'OS-EXT-IPS:type': 'fixed',
      'OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr': 'fa:16:3e:e1:95:33'
    }
  ]
},
accessIPv4=,
accessIPv6=
```

and my code :

```
data = getproject()

for pj in project:
    for dt in data:
        if pj.project == dt["name"]:
            pj.addr = dt["addresses"]["int-ext"][0]["addr"]
```

I want to get the IP address and I try to print, but the output still "None" in running code . this code error when I run in python3

Comment: It looks like *name* is not a part of your **json** and *addresses* is a dictionary itself, not a key in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you please include the error seen when you run the script ?  Also, Can you please post the full JSON file.     In the above, I see that "addresses" is not a string so wanted to confirm the full JSON file.

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation? It's confusing.

Comment: this my json data  : https://pastebin.com/SJdjH8aB , and I wanna to get the IP Address from int-ext @AstikGabani

error script when I print(pj.addr) the output is : None

Comment: Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: this data from response openstack api list servers. @bigbounty